# Hosting a homepage on godaddy

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy

I have a web hosting account with godaddy. How do you make it so entering just the domain name will take you to the home page? 
For example `www.coolwebsite.com` vs `www.coolwebsite.com/page1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have index.html or index.htm in the root of your account.  I believe you can also have index.php and default.htm.

You might want to look at -
http://support.godaddy.com/help/60/what-file-displays-when-someone-browses-to-my-domain-name
This page has a link to the order of precedence for the various filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on which web server you use, you can do server side redirect (search for "web server name" + redirect). Or try the following meta tag to do client side redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/page1">
```

Put the below code to your index.html, which is the file that is served when you access your domain without path.